# Browser closes connection after receiving HTTP response from custom webserver

Tags: c++, http, webserver

I work on a simple C++ HTTP server on Windows. Once the server responds to a browser, the browser closes the connection while it shouldn't because I use the `keep-alive` connection header in my HTTP response headers.

Code looks like this:

```cpp
void WebServer::HttpRespondToClient(SOCKET ClientSocket,std::string& Content,int ErrorCode)
{
    std::stringstream Response;
    Response << "HTTP/1.1 " << ErrorCode << " OK\r\n"
        << "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << Content.size() << "\r\n"
        << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        << "Keep-Alive: timeout=50, max=1000\r\n" << "\r\n"
        << Content << "\r\n";


    std::string ResponseStr = Response.str();
    sendToClient(ClientSocket, ResponseStr.c_str(), ResponseStr.size() + 1);
}
```

I confirmed with inspect element that the browser receives the headers normally.

[image]

Comment: Your response is malformed. DO NOT send a trailing `\r\n` after the `Content`, and DO NOT send the `ResponseStr`s null terminator.

Comment: `Connection: keep-alive` is not part of HTTP/1.1, and if it was it would be for the client to set, not the server. Connection pooling is the default in HTTP/1.1, but either end can close after any request/response pair.

Comment: @user207421 "*Connection: keep-alive is not part of HTTP/1.1*" - we can't see the raw client request, so we don't know whether it is actually using HTTP 1.0 or 1.1. The code shown is not checking for that and adjusting itself accordingly. But even so, we can see a `Connection: keep-alive` header in the request, so sending a `Connection: keep-alive` header in the response is not unexpected, or illegal.

Answer (score 1):

@RemyLebeau is right:

> Your response is malformed. DO NOT send a trailing `\r\n` after the `Content`, and DO NOT send the `ResponseStr`s null terminator

I changed my code to:

```cpp
void WebServer::HttpRespondToClient(SOCKET ClientSocket,std::string& Content,int ErrorCode)
{
    std::stringstream Response;
    Response << "HTTP/1.1 " << ErrorCode << " OK\r\n"
        << "Cache-Control: no-cache, private\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << Content.size() << "\r\n"
        << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        << "Keep-Alive: timeout=50, max=1000\r\n" << "\r\n"
        << Content;


    std::string ResponseStr = Response.str();
    sendToClient(ClientSocket, ResponseStr.c_str(), ResponseStr.size());
}
```

and it works just fine, thanks a lot for saving my time!!!